# VueJS Register component error Unknown custom element

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I have problem with register component in VueJS. I installed the component from https://github.com/wanxe/vue-button-spinner with `npm install`. Next I add code to my app.js (I'm using Laravel 5.5).

My app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Spinner from './components/Spinner.vue'

window.onload = function () {

    Vue.component('button-spinner', require('./components/Spinner.vue'));
    var vw = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'button-spinner': Spinner
        }
    });

};
```

And Spinner.vue code

```
<script>
    import VueButtonSpinner from 'vue-button-spinner';

    console.log('Test');

    export default {
        name: 'events-form',
        data() {
            return {
                isLoading: false,
                status: '',
            }
        },
        components: {
            VueButtonSpinner
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                this.isLoading = true
                $someRequest('/url', 'GET')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.isLoading = false
                        this.status = true // or success
                        setTimeout(() => { this.status = '' }, 2000) // to clear the status :)
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error)
                        this.isLoading = false
                        this.status = false //or error
                    })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

After this I run `npm run dev`
Next I add code to my HTML

```
<div id="app">
 <button-spinner
                        :isLoading="isLoading"
                        :disabled="isLoading"
                        :status="status">
                <input type="submit" :disabled="submitted" :class="{ 'disabled': submitted == true }" @click="submit('register', $event)"
                       v-model="registerSubmit" id="registerSubmit" style="width: 100%; height: 40px">
                </button-spinner>

</div>
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

And component is not working. I don't known why. Console prints `Unknown custom element: <button-spinner>`

[image]

EDIT:

I remove `window.onload = function ()` from app.js after this `console.log('Component mounted.')` is working but from Spinner I gets `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.found in---> <ButtonSpinner> at resources/assets/js/components/Spinner.vue<Root>`

After remove `window.onload` there was another problem I also link additional js files in html

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/login.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/register.js')}}"></script>
```

This scripts using VueJS and procudes a lot of errors.

[image]

With `window.onload` everything was ok. Should I include this files in `app.js`? Eg. `register.js` file https://pastebin.com/0uHxRcN9

app.js after update:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');


require('./bootstrap');

import Spinner from './components/Spinner.vue'

    require('./register');
    require('./login');
   new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
            'button-spinner': Spinner
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You created component both ways

Remove this

```
Vue.component('button-spinner', require('./components/Spinner.vue'));
```

And Change here

```
components: {
    buttonSpinner: Spinner
}
```

Also putting html inside component will not work as you put `input` , remove this

```
<input type="submit" :disabled="submitted" ....
```

Also use `props`  to pass params in child components

```
props = ["isLoading","disabled","status"]
```

and use define this in main component

```
isLoading: false,
status: '',
```

Comment: I change this but still not working, Also  `console.log('Component mounted.')` is not display in console. Maybe the problem is with `window.onload = function ()`?

Comment: if you doubted on `window.onload` remove that line and check

Comment: @lukassz : did you find any changes ?

Comment: @lukassz : shift this code to main component `isLoading: false,
status: '',` and use props in child component

Comment: @lukassz : when you say not working , share what is not working and what error you got ?

Comment: you did not set `error` and used , either remove for now or set as false

Comment: @user2486 this properties are in  `require('./register');` and `require('./login');`

Comment: @lukassz : you are getting for `error` remove this or set error as false and check

Comment: if you still gettting this `Property or method "error" is not defined` then you need to set `error` where you are using not in parent component

Comment: Yes, but I have a problem with all of my properties eg. `Property or method "success" is not defined`. Incorrectly links js files in `app.js`? Where exactly should I set the error and the rest?

Comment: you need put all these where there component is , means inside components

Comment: Please share small live demo so that I can make you understand where you are getting problem ?

Comment: Ok, I do this later

Comment: I add my code on https://jsfiddle.net/lukassz/htqqo5px/ and errors pastebin.com/EFDV6WiM

Comment: `pastebin.com/EFDV6WiM` url is ban in our country.

Comment: I just check you code , you mixed laravel and vuejs. remove all code from laravel if you want do it by vuejs.

Comment: We should not refresh page to old value rather we can use ajax

Comment: Ok, I correct this. I know, I have not done refactoring yet

Comment: Also you didn't initialize `registerName` as error shows

Comment: I use `registerName` only in `el: '#register-container'`

Comment: you can check in error log `Property or method "registerName" is not defined`.  If Its not sensitive ans small project you can share git repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159699/discussion-between-lukassz-and-user2486).

Answer (score 0):

Vue seems to use convert ComponentName to component-name when you register a component inline. Your problem can easily be fixed by changing your 'import alias'
to `ButtonSpinner`

```
import ButtonSpinner from './components/Spinner.vue'

//in the components property 
components: {
   ButtonSpinner
}
```